# How to set result size zero in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Consider the following elasticsearch query :

```
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}},
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
      "Terms": { "terms": { "field":"fileName" }
      }
   }
}
```

Here I'm just interested in the aggregation and not in the documents. That's why I set `size:0` and it works as expected. However I'm unable to achieve the same with `spring-data`. Code sample :

```
PageRequest page = new PageRequest(0, 0);
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withIndices(indexName).withTypes(typeName)
                .withQuery(queryBuilder).withAggregation(aggsBuilder)
                .withPageable(pageable).build();
```

This `PageRequest` constructor throws an exception then, which is from its parent:

```
public AbstractPageRequest(int page, int size) {
    if (page < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Page index must not be less than zero!");
    }
    if (size < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Page size must not be less than one!");
    }
    this.page = page;
    this.size = size;
}
```

Question : Is there any way in spring data to limit document size to zero ?

Comment: @Mohsin Husen : I need your help here !

Comment: Which version of ES and Spring Data ES are you using?

Comment: ES version 1.3.4 and spring-data-es 1.1.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can define empty pageable interface implementation class, like this:

```
public static class EmptyPage implements Pageable {
    public static final EmptyPage INSTANCE = new EmptyPage();

    @Override
    public int getPageNumber() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPageSize() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOffset() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Sort getSort() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Pageable next() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Pageable previousOrFirst() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Pageable first() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(queryBuilder)
            .withIndices(indexName).withTypes(typeName)
            .addAggregation(aggsBuilder)
            .withPageable(EmptyPage.INSTANCE)
            .build();
```

Result:

```
{
  "aggregations": { ... },
  "from": 0,
  "query": { ... },
  "size": 0
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0 on, `NativeSearchQuery`, `StringQuery` and `CriteriaQuery` have a method `setMaxResults(Integer maxResults)`

so the query would be

```java
NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withIndices(indexName).withTypes(typeName)
                .withQuery(queryBuilder).withAggregation(aggsBuilder)
                .build();

searchQuery.setMaxResults(0);
```

The `setMaxResults()` method returns `void` so can't be used with the builder syntax

This will add `"size":0` at the top of the request object

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ES 1.x, what you can do is leave out the `Pageable` and specify the search type `COUNT` instead.

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withIndices(indexName).withTypes(typeName)
            .withQuery(queryBuilder).withAggregation(aggsBuilder)
            .withSearchType(SearchType.COUNT).build();
```

As of ES 2.x, `SearchType.COUNT` will be deprecated and not available anymore, but for ES 1.x needs this should do the job.

Note that there's a [similar need](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-112) for other users, too, but the issue is still open.

Comment: May be you are not getting my question or I'm missing the point in your answer. I see that `withSearchType(SearchType.COUNT)` sets a search type, but where I will be putting it's value to 0 ?

Comment: You don't, the [count search type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/search-request-search-type.html#count) will never send you documents back, only aggregation results.

Comment: What to do for ES 5.x as SearchType.COUNT is removed?

Comment: @Pratz I think you might have to use a page of size 1: `PageRequest(0, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but may be of use for future developers. The way for me was to define a new class `PageRequest` that implements `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` and the resembles `org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest` but does not have constraints of `AbstractPageRequest` on size.
Then you can pass it to your builder.

Comment: I agree with you. Just use the PagingAndSortingRepository in your interface which enables you to request elastic search. And return Page <yourClass>.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1561)

It would be useful to have a "withMaxResults" method to NativeSearchQueryBuilder for specifying the maxResults on the built Query. This is common for aggregation queries where search hits are not needed.

Having the builder method for setting maxResults is a minor ergonomic improvement, e.g.

```
NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
    .addAggregation(terms("examples").field("example"))
    .withMaxResults(0)
    .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is to set `"size": 0` in code?

Paging is not supported in aggregations, so the `PageRequest` will not be entertained. The error is because page limit cannot be 0. What you need is:

```
        SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                        .withIndices(indexName).withTypes(typeName)
                        .withQuery(queryBuilder)
                        .withAggregation(aggsBuilder.size(0)) //set the size with AggregationBuilders
                        .withSearchType(SearchType.COUNT)                        
                        .build();
```

Comment: First of all : you didn't get my question at all. Second you edit my question to express another meaning which you are answering ! I don't blame you, but it's not good. Val has answered it properly although I haven't verified yet.