# PageRequest doesn't allow size to be zero, how can we set the size to zero in a elasticsearch NativeSearchQueryBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

At the moment `org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest` doesn't allow size to be zero, in fact there is a check on this in the `AbstractPageRequest` constructor.
So how are we supposed to set the size to zero in a `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder`?
The point being that is possible to set a size of 0 on a `org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder`. In fact there is a well known use case where one should set the size to zero: "I am just interested in the aggregation result and not in the documents found by the query".

Here is a snapshot of my code which is throwing the `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = (SearchQuery) new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                    .withIndices(indices).withTypes(types)
                    .withQuery(query).addAggregation(agg)
                    .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 0)).build();
```

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37209682/4604579

Comment: Thank you. I can't understand how the issue has evolved, do you have any clue about it?