# Getting only aggregations results in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am doing aggregation like this:

```
  {
   "size":0,
   "aggs":
    {
      "my_aggs":
      {
         "terms":
          {
            "field":"my_field"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to get only the aggregation result. So when I set `size=0` like below, it gives error-later learned this is for how many results I want(aggregations). So, **how can I achieve this to get only the aggregation results(no hits result docs)**

```
AbstractAggregationBuilder aggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders
                .terms("my_aggs")
                .field("my_field")
                .size(0) //how to set size for my purpose?
                .order(BucketOrder.key(true));
```

Moreover, **If I get thousands of aggregation results, does this query return all of them? or apply to its default 10 size? If not, how do know how many should I set size of aggregation result.**
**Edit** I am adding my aggregation like this:

```
 SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withIndices(indexName)
                .withTypes(typeName)
                .withQuery(boolQueryBuilder)
                .addAggregation(aggregationBuilder)
                .build();
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that on the SearchRequest instance not at the aggregation level:

```
AbstractAggregationBuilder aggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders
            .terms("my_aggs")
            .field("my_field")
            .order(BucketOrder.key(true));

SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withIndices(indexName)
            .withTypes(typeName)
            .withQuery(boolQueryBuilder)
            .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 1))       <--- add this
            .addAggregation(aggregationBuilder)
            .build();
```

As far as I know, Spring Data ES doesn't allow you to create a `PageRequest` with size 0 (hence why I picked 1). If that's a problem, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42918377/4604579) shows you how to override that behavior.

By default, your aggregation will return 10 buckets, but you can increase the size up to 10000, if needed.

Comment: according to the link, we can use " .withMaxResults(0)"
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1561

Comment: Same results with ".setPageable(Pageable.ofSize(1));"